# Representations of commutative Lie groups

Tags: group-theory

Considering the following definition for a representation of a Lie group (see W.-K. Tung - Group Theory in Physics):

> If there is a homomorphism from a group $G$ to a group of operators $U(G)$ on a linear vector space $V$, we say that $U(G)$ forms a representation of the group $G$.

Do commutative Lie groups have exactly the same representations? Why?

Comment: What makes you think that this doesn't apply to Abelian (commutative) groups?

Comment: I'm not restricting to Abelian groups but considering the case of a group which commutes with all the generators of a different non-Abelian group. For example, one can consider a group G composed by the direct sum of a non-Abelian group G1 and a group G2 with a generator that commutes with all the generators of G1. Then, are the representations of G exactly the same as the representations of G1? If not, are there any additional conditions to get such an equivalence?

Comment: @albert_st define "exactly the same representations". Obviously homomorphisms from different groups cannot be "exactly the same" sensu stricto.

Comment: see W.-K. Tung, Theorem 11.7: (Unitary Irreducible Representations of O(3)): The unitary irreducible representations of O(3) are labelled by (j, \eta) where j = 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, . . ., and \eta =-1,+1. The matrix representation of rotations are the same as in SO(3) and the matrix for the space inversion is \eta times the identity matrix. The parameter \eta is referred to as the parity of this representation.                                         Please, any idea?